# Tool to list memory-mapped I/O in C source code

Tags: c, static-analysis, patternmatching

I try to find a light-weight tool to detect some line of C code then get information.

For example, I want to detect the code which performs Memory-mapped I/O in embedded software. This code often appears as the form below:

```
int *device = (int *)address;
*device = value;
```

The information I want to get are: the line number of this code and the string "address" and "value" as they are variables' name.

I found that extending Flawfinder, RATS or Graudit, which use pattern matching technique, may be suitable for my purpose. So I want to ask:

1. Are those tool still maintained?
2. Is it possible and easy to extend those tools?
3. Do you have any recommendation for me to solve this task?

Many thanks,